# How to use spring cloud config server with postgresql and jdbc as backend with multiple profiles?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I'm able to connect to postgres using spring cloud config server with only bootstrap.yml file.

But I have multiple environments like dev,test and prod. So I want to create separate profiles for each environment(like bootstap-dev.properties) and change the url datasource url accordingly.

Can anyone please suggest me regarding the same ?

**bootstrap.yml:**

```
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  application:
    name: myapp
  profiles:
    active: jdbc
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/config_db
    username: XXXX
    password: XXXX
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          sql: SELECT key, value FROM properties WHERE application=? AND profile=? AND label=?;
        order: 0
        default-label: default
    bus:
      trace:
        enabled: true
  security:
    user:
      name: XXX
      password: XXX
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: bus-refresh,health
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to use in the spring cloud.
First, create an application.properties that content only follow like this `spring.profiles.active=dev`

Second, to modify your dev application.properties name to application-dev.properties.
Ok, then put them into your resources directory together.

Others, you can create another file of environments with different suffixes, such as `application-test.properties` or `application-pro.properties`..., and only change the active value to the suffix name. like this `spring.profiles.active=test`

My best to you.

Comment: It is my pleasure.